# tcp connection refused

Tags: tcp, connection, failed

I am getting following error when running a program

```
2011/07/06 18:21:08 stat http error: dial tcp localhost:3179: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3179: connection refused
2011/07/06 18:21:08 Error putting file: stat http error: dial tcp localhost:3179: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3179: connection refused
```

What can be the reason for this

Comment: I think  you need to provide us with more details.  What are you trying to do? What software are you running? What operating system are you using? Do you expect something to be listening on port 3179?  Is it running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

without a more detail I would say that nothing is listening on port 3179 on localhost. If you're in Linux do

> 'netstat -an|grep :3179'

to see if any process is attached to that port. If in Windows there's a similar command (without the grep) to see the same info I think - consult our local windows manual :)

Comment: The Windows notation is `netstat -an | find /I ":3179"`

Comment: This is a very handy Linux command.